# Using MongoDB Aggregator Framework to format data that match with chartjs scatter

Tags: mongodb, charts, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm new using aggregators in MongoDB and I'm wondering if there is a way to format data at MongoDB level to prepare the results for plotting with [ChartJs scatter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html).

So I have a time series dataset (I'm not sure that this is the best way to store time-series data, so any advice is welcome) that looks like this:

```
{
    "dataset_id" : "850919c9-30e4-46f1-b962-e6b16cd30c60",
    "time_stamp" : 1600624542,
    "series" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "serie_0",
            "value" : 935.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "serie_1",
            "value" : 780.0
        }, 
        ...
        {
            "name" : "serie_n",
            "value" : <value_n>
        }, 
     ]
}
```

But for ChartJS I need a format like:

```
[
    {
      label: '<series_0_name>',
      data: [
        {x: <timestamp>, y: <value>},
        ...
        {x: <timestamp>, y: <value>},
       ]
    },
    ...
    {
      label: '<series_n_name>',
      data: [
        {x: <timestamp>, y: <value>},
        ...
        {x: <timestamp>, y: <value>},
       ]
    },
]
```

To archive this at this moment I'm using this python code (I'm using PyMongo):

```
def dataset_format(dataset_id, sample_size):
    match = {"$match": {"dataset_id": str(dataset_id)}}
    sample = {"$sample": {"size": sample_size}}
    unwind = {"$unwind": {"path": "$series"}}
    stages = [match, sample, unwind]

    pool = DB_POOL_COLLECTION.aggregate(stages)
    values = [
        (record["series"]["name"], record["time_stamp"], record["series"]["value"])
        for record in pool
    ]

    data = [
        {"label": d, "data": [{"x": v[1], "y": v[2]} for v in values if v[0] == d]}
        for d in set(name[0] for name in values)
    ]

    return data
```

But thinking on a performance I think that moving this python formatting code to the MongoDb side I will increase the performance of my query. Also As I say before This project is starting from scratch so I'm open to suggestions about the Document style of my DB, thinking on I need a good performance on reading but I don't care about writing performance right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it in this way, I still not sure if is the most efficient approach but the performance now is very good

```
def dataset_info(dataset_id, sample_size):
    stages = [
        {"$match": {"dataset_id": str(dataset_id)}},
        {"$sample": {"size": sample_size}},
        {"$sort": {"time_stamp": 1}},
        {"$unwind": {"path": "$series"}},
        {
            "$project": {
                "label": "$series.name",
                "data": {
                    "x": {"$multiply": ["$time_stamp", 1000]},
                    "y": "$series.value",
                },
            }
        },
        {"$group": {"_id": "$label", "data": {"$push": "$data"}}},
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "label": "$_id",
                "data": 1,
                "showLine": {"$toBool": 1},
                "fill": {"$toBool": 0},
            }
        },
        {"$sort": {"label": 1}},
    ]

    data = DB_POOL_COLLECTION.aggregate(stages)
    return list(data)
```

This returns data structure ready for ChartJS like:

```
[
    {
      label: '<series_0_name>',
      showLine: true,
      fill: false,
      data: [
        {x: <timestamp in ms>, y: <value>},
        ...
        {x: <timestamp in ms>, y: <value>},
       ]
    },
    ...
    {
      label: '<series_n_name>',
      showLine: true,
      fill: false,
      data: [
        {x: <timestamp in ms>, y: <value>},
        ...
        {x: <timestamp in ms>, y: <value>},
       ]
    },
]
```